# Android studio open many java process

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jvm

Machine spec:

- MacBook Pro M1 Pro.
- Sonoma (14.2).
- 16g of RAM.
- Android studio Giraffe Patch 3 last stable update (08/11/2023)

I'm having a problem in my android studio projects when I try to run any project android studio start to open one java process and in the middle of operation open another one and another one until they become 2 or 3 every single one of them take at least 6g of RAM as I describe in my `gradle.properties`, this make my build really slow in a very huge project (74 module project) that I'm working on.

## Here you can find my `gradle.properties` file

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g`

`org.gradle.parallel=true`

`org.gradle.caching=true`

`org.gradle.configureondemand=true`

`org.gradle.daemon=true`

`kotlin.incremental=true`

`kotlin.code.style=official`

`android.nonTransitiveRClass=true`

`org.gradle.daemon.idletimeout=60000`

`android.enableJetifier=true`

## Here you can find my environment variable in shell system (.zshrc)

[image]

## Here you can find my process when android studio open it

[image]

That's all I have right now, if you wanna help please ask for anything you need :D

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem as well and managed to fix it by changing the Gradle JDK in File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle. Moving to Oracle to JetBrains seemed to fix it.

Comment: Should I put JetBrain JDK as JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're looking as the place I pointed you doesn't list JAVA_HOME as a variable. I set my Gradle JDK in the are I pointed to to Jetbrains.